# TypeError: object of type 'types.GenericAlias' has no len()

Tags: python

I have one question,  regarding why object of type "~~~" no len()

```
class testing:
def findrepeatnum(self, nums: list[int]) -> int:
    i = 0
    while i < len(nums):
        if nums[i] == i:
            i += 1
            continue
        if nums[nums[i]] == nums[i]:
            return nums[i]
        nums[nums[i]], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[nums[i]]
    return -1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = list[2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 1]
    res = testing().findrepeatnum(num)
    print(res)
```

This code gives me TypeError: object of type 'types.GenericAlias' has no len(). This confuses me for a long time. If I build the function like this:

```
def findrepeatnum(self, nums: list[int]) -> int:
i = 0
while i < len(nums):
    if nums[i] == i:
        i += 1
        continue
    if nums[nums[i]] == nums[i]:
        return nums[i]
    nums[nums[i]], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[nums[i]]
return -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = list[2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 1]
    res = findrepeatnum(num)
    print(res)
```

The code gives me TypeError: findrepeatnum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nums' but the nums is already the parameter. I want to know how I can write this correctly.
Thank you very very much!

Comment: Please provide us a description of what your whole function is expected to do with a few example of input and output.

Comment: Your code looks like C code. Not python. We can help you for that too.

Comment: I think this would help you: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.trainingint.com/how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-python-list.html/amp (method 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of num should be:

```py
num = [2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 1]
# or
num = list([2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 1])
```

`list[int]` is used to specify that the values in the list are integer values.
so we cannot use list[] to define a list.